# Como mudar a cor de um select da FLAT-UI sem usar less?

Tags: html, html5, twitter-bootstrap, flat-ui

É possível mudar a cor de um select (do `data-toggle` select, incluindo as opções) da Flat-UI por CSS sem usar `less`?.

Neste <kbd>[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bbuxtLkk/)</kbd> que o @dHEKU postou nos comentários, a cor do `select` padrão já foi modificada, mas faltam as `options`, **principalmente** a cor da `option` que aparece quando o `select` é aberto.

Já tentei de algumas formas:

```
.select .select-primary {

    background-color: #000066;
}
select {

    background-color: #000066;
}
```

Mas não funcionou.  O HTML está assim:

```
<label class="control-label" for="select">
<select id="select" name="selectname" class="form-control select select-primary" data-toggle="select">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select></label>
```

Comment: Olá, eu tentei responder, mas parece que o js do `flat-ui` cria várias classes escondidas e acaba que fica muito chato modificar qualquer coisa. http://jsfiddle.net/bbuxtLkk/ - Só não conseguir saber qual é a classe que modifica o hover do `option`.

Comment: Valeu pela tentativa @dHEKU. Acho que não tem jeito mesmo, só utilizando `less` deve ser possível, ou mudando pelo padrão de cores (swatche).  De qualquer forma, acho que seu comentário seria válido como resposta.

Comment: Não entendi bem... No exemplo do jsFiddle mencionado na pergunta, o que estas a tentar mudar é a cor do background que neste momento é cinzento onde diz `chose hero, spider man ... etc`, a cor onde está o cor-de-laranja ou é a cor da setinha do dropdown?

Comment: Quando vc abre o select, aparece o `xmen` em verde, e quando vc passa o mouse em cima e depois tira do select, a opção que estava quando saiu do select fica em verde tbm. É principalmente isso... A cor da transição entre as opções nem precisa...

Comment: E no exemplo do fiddle já mudou a cor que aparece default (era verde)...A cor do background das opções tbm não precisa mudar, só este verde irritante mesmo. :-)

Comment: Algo assim deste genero? - http://jsfiddle.net/jg6wdvjy/

Comment: Rá! É isso mesmo! Posta aí como resposta! Valeu!

Comment: Então @Chun, se estiver animado, acabei de abrir uma recompensa de 100 [nesta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71102/como-validar-formato-e-comparar-duas-datas-para-habilitar-bot%C3%B5es). Tudo por uma noite de sexta mais divertida! :-)

Comment: hehehe, eu já estava mesmo de saída quando entrei aqui nessa pergunta. já são 5:00 da manhã aqui em Portugal xD amanha vejo isso, agora vou dormir. Abraços

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estive ali a dar uma vista de olhos no jsFiddle e consegui ver onde este estilo é aplicado.
Para mudares a cor do `background` verde para outra cor, basta aplicar este pedaço de código CSS:

```
/* Muda a cor verde para preto */
.select2-drop .select2-highlighted>.select2-result-label {
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
}
```

No entanto ao postar aqui a minha resposta usando o **`Code-Snippet`** eu reparei que este CSS não está a ser aplicado, provavelmente por causa da ordem de estilos. Então teremos que usar um `!important` para **obrigar** a que isto funcione em qualquer das situações:

```
/* Muda a cor verde para preto */
.select2-drop .select2-highlighted>.select2-result-label {
    color: #fff;
    background: #000 !important;
}
/* Necessário por causa do !important adicionado anteriormente */
.select2-result-selectable .select2-result-label:hover,
.select2-drop .select2-result-selectable .select2-result-label:active {
    background-color: #e1e4e7 !important;
}
```

Eis um exemplo abaixo e também tens aqui um <kbd>[**exemplo no jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jg6wdvjy/1)</kbd> se preferires.

```css
/* Muda a cor verde para preto */
.select2-drop .select2-highlighted>.select2-result-label {
    color: #fff;
    background: #000 !important;
}
/* Necessário por causa do !important adicionado anteriormente */
.select2-result-selectable .select2-result-label:hover,
.select2-drop .select2-result-selectable .select2-result-label:active {
    background-color: #e1e4e7 !important;
}


.select-exemploa .select2-choice {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #E87E04;
}
.select-exemploa .select2-choice:hover,
.select-exemploa .select2-choice.hover,
.select-exemploa .select2-choice:focus,
.select-exemploa .select2-choice:active {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #F4B350;
    border-color: #d35400;
}
.select-exemploa .select2-choice:active {
    background: #F9690E;
    border-color: #d35400;
}
.select2-container-disabled.select-exemploa .select2-choice,
.select2-container-disabled.select-exemploa .select2-choice:hover,
.select2-container-disabled.select-exemploa .select2-choice:focus,
.select2-container-disabled.select-exemploa .select2-choice:active {
    background-color: #F9690E;
    border-color: #d35400;
}
.select-exemploa .select2-choice .select2-arrow {
    border-top-color: #fff;
}

.select-exemploa {
    margin-top: 32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/dist/css/flat-ui.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/dist/css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/dist/js/flat-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/docs/assets/js/application.js"></script>


<select class="form-control select select-exemploa" data-toggle="select">
    <option value="0">Choose hero</option>
    <option value="1">Spider Man</option>
    <option value="2">Wolverine</option>
    <option value="3">Captain America</option>
    <option value="4" selected>X-Men</option>
    <option value="5">Crocodile</option>
</select>
```